# react component prompt box or useState or useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

in react component I am using a prompt box to take city from user.everything is working fine but the prompt box is showing up two times.please help if this can be done or help me using usestate or useeffect hooks.or should I use class component.i am looking for east an approach.....I am newbie in react.

Many Thanks

```js
import React from 'react'
    
const SearchArea = ({Country}) => {
  var city = prompt("Please enter your city")
  return (
    <div>
      {countires.map(c => {
        if (c.area == city) {
          return (
            <div>{c.area}</div>
          )
        }
      })}  
    <div>
  )
}
    
export default SearchArea
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code. Where are the useState calls? You also have a couple of issues in your code: the `countires` is a typo (maybe needs to be `Country`?), your closing div should be `</div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'useState' and 'useEffect', you can achieve the same as follows:

```
import React from 'react'

const SearchArea = ({Country}) => {
    const [city, setCity] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
       const city = prompt("Please enter your city");
       setCity(city);

    }, [])
    
    return (
      <div>
      {
         countires.map(c => {
           if (c.area == city) {
            return (
              <div>
                {c.area}

              </div>
            )
           }
        })
     }  
    <div>
  
  )
}

export default SearchArea
```

Comment: Thanks Sir .....it solved my problem.....actually I am using a link on my toolbar "enter city" so that user can enter city........now how I can reload this component every time I click "enter city" link.......so that prompt box appears again so that user can put new city search.........Many Thanks

Comment: Instead of `useEffect` prompt on button click and set state within that call

Comment: ok cool ....Thanks.....can I turn the prompt text into Lower case.Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

i prefer using input to do that, but i have solution for promp like this :

```js
const SearchArea = ({Country}) => {
  const [found, setfound] = React.useState(null);
  const handleClick = () => {
    const city = prompt("Please enter your city", "rasht");
    if (city !== null) {
      const search = Country.find((c) => c.city === city);
      if (search) setfound(search.country);
      else setfound("not found!");
    }
  };
  return found ? <h2>{found}</h2> : <button onClick={handleClick} >search for city</button>;
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <SearchArea Country={[
    { country: "iran", city: "rasht" },
    { country: "italy", city: "sicily" },
    { country: "spain", city: "madrid" }
  ]} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```